# attributes & facets are not visible in Fredhopper for some publication

Tags: fredhopper

we have configured attributes & facets in business.xml file,same file working in staging site but in production it does not work.

when we published it is indexing but facets does not appear,even in preview mode does not show facets.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a few possible reasons why facets don’t work on production. To help you further can you let us know a bit information more about your setup?
Are staging and production site linked to each other? Are data on staging and production in sync?

In any case, you might want to check the synchronisation (client/server) log files, on both the live and staging server.